# SXW to RML using python openerp

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

When i trying to convert .sxw to pdf file using openerp_sxw2rml.py in windows i m getting following error.

```
openerp_swx2rml.py ABG-ADD_decpages.sxw > testfile.rml
  File "C:\JRA\PythonEnv\pdf2rml\src\openerp_swx2rml.py", line 140
    if self.styles_dom.getElementsByTagName("style:page-master").__len__()<>0:
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i tried using tiny_sxw2rml also. i m using python 3. The result is same. Help me out to Resolve it.

Comment: Which Odoo version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple python syntax error at `if` statement line.

**Actually this (`<>`) is the operator to check *not equal to* but now it has been removed from python3**

```
if self.styles_dom.getElementsByTagName("style:page-master").__len__()<>0:
```

You have used wrong comparison syntax to check the length with 0.

If you want to check greater than 0 then simple use `>`  else `<` .

So, in case of greater you can replace this line as

```
if self.styles_dom.getElementsByTagName("style:page-master").__len__() > 0:
```